# Message "Do you want to re-activate Invantive Control functions.xlam" on every start of Excel

Tags: invantive-control

On every start of Excel I receive a pop-up asking me whether to re-activate Invantive Control functions.xlam. This is a xlam from the add-on Invantive Control.

Even when I answer "Yes", the same question appears again on the next start.

How can I permanently say "Yes" and have it activated always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the list of installed add-ins in File -> Options -> Add-ins.

Typically the following Excel add-ins will be active:

- Analysis Toolpak
- and/or Microsoft Power ...

Depending on load order somehow the Analysis Toolpak or Microsoft Power (Map/View/Pivot) de-activates the loading of other Excel Add-ins. COM Excel Add-ins are not hindered.

The solution is to change the load order:

- Deactivate in Excel add-ins the Analysis Toolpak and Analysis Toolpak - VBA.
- Deactivate in COM add-ins the Microsoft Power Map, Microsoft Power Pivot and Microsoft Power View.
- Restart Excel.
- Answer "Yes" on the question.
- Activate again in Excel add-ins the Analysis Toolpak and Analysis Toolpak - VBA.
- Activate again in COM add-ins the Microsoft Power Map, Microsoft Power Pivot and Microsoft Power View.
- Restart Excel.

Loading of all add-ins is then fixed. The actual reason why Excel or the other add-ins disable the XLAM is unknown.